# SQL Parse NVARCHAR Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, ssis

I am loading data from Excels into database on SQL Server 2008. There is one column which is in `nvarchar` data type. This field contains the data as

```
Text text text text text    text text text text text.
(ABC-2010-4091, ABC-2011-0586,     ABC-2011-0587, ABC-2011-0604)     
Text text text text text    text text text text text. 
(ABC-2011-0562,     ABC-2011-0570, ABC-2011-0575, ABC-2011-0588)
```

so its text with many sentences of this kind.

For each row I need to get the data `ABC-####-####`, respectivelly I only need the last part. So e.g. for `ABC-2010-4091` I need to obtain `4091`. This number I will need to join to other table. I guess it would be enough to get the last parts of the format `ABC-####-####`, then I should be able to handle the request.

So the example of given above, the result should be `4091, 0586, 0587, 0604, 0562, 0570, 0575, 0588` in the row instead of the whole nvarchar value field.

Is this possible somehow? The text in the nvarchar field differ, but the text format (ABC-####-####) I want to work with is still the same. Only the count of characters for the last part may vary so its not only 4 numbers, but could be 5 or more.

What is the best approach to get these data? Should I parse it in SSIS or on the SQL server side with SQL Query? And how?

I am aware this is though task. I appreciate every help or advice how to deal with this. I have not tried anything yet as I do not know where to start. I read articles about SQL parsing, but I want to ask for best approach to deal with this task.

Comment: I disagree with TomTom -- I don't think parsing in SQL is that bad... but it is slow-performing.  If you do it in SQL, a few pseudo-code recommendations:  use a `WHILE` to go thru the string, and use `'[A-Za-z]'` as wildcarding to detect alphabetic characters, and `'[0-9]'` for numerics... so you could use something like `PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @input_string)` to detect `@start_pos`, and something like `SUBSTRING(@input_string, @start_pos + 10, 4)` to get those last 4 digits.  (The loop, testing, and fine-tuning... I'm leaving to you ;)

Comment: Thanks, at least I have some starting point :) will give it a try. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked this problem out with the following guides:

[Split Multi Value Column into Multiple Records](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.se/2012/11/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html) 
 & 
[Remove Multiple Spaces with Only One Space](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/34ce1b87-fee7-48c9-b3aa-9615de138bbc/how-to-replace-multiple-blanks-into-one?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is about programming.

Sit down and start programming.

Ok, seriously. That is string parsing and the last part in brackets with multiple fields means no bulk import, it is not a standard CSV file.

Either you use SSIS in SQL Server and program the parsing there or.... you write a program for that.

String maniupation in SQL is the worst part of the language and I would avoid it.

So, yes, sit down and program a routine. Probable the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, "ABS-####-####" will be the value coming through in the column and the numeric part is variable in length.

If that is the case, maybe this will work.

Use a "Derived Column" transformation. 
Lets say we call "ABC-####-####" = Column1

```
SUBSTRING("Column1",(FINDSTRING("Column1","-",2)+1),LEN(Column1)-(FINDSTRING("Column1","-",2)))
```

If I am not mistaken, that should give you the last # values in a new column no matter how long that value is.

HTH

Comment: I tired that but it was not the right choice to me. Maybe I have made some mistake. However, the guide on this link http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.se/2012/11/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html has helped me out a lot.